# buildroot - how to build tool v4l2-ctl?

Tags: buildroot

I want to build v4l2-ctl tool in buildroot (from 2019.02.4) linux system.

But v4l2-ctl is legacy (has been deprecated and replaced by a single option to build all the libv4l utilities).

I try to setup BR2_PACKAGE_LIBV4L_UTILS, to get v4l2-ctl, but after make, in linux system there is no v4l2-clt tool.

Do not understand: where is v4l2-ctl? How to build v4l2-ctl?

Answer (score 1):

I got it:

It is need to rebuild buildroot's packet again:
make libv4l-dirclean
then
make libv4l-rebuild
then
make

and v4l2-ctl will appear in target usr/bin directory

Answer (score 1):

You can read good article about v4l-utils and meson build system [here](https://habr.com/ru/articles/724818/).